# Is this integral $\int mgdy=\int_{0}^S mg \frac{1}{2}g\frac{(dx)^2}{v^2}$ possible?

Tags: calculus, integration, stochastic-calculus

I stumbled on a very simple problem yet I was awestruck when I saw the integral. This is a solution of work done by our muscle when we move horizontally in air a distance $S$. I couldn't see the solution. Please help me understand the integral and the calculations involved!

Thanks!

$$\int mgdy=\int_{0}^S  mg \frac{1}{2}g\frac{(dx)^2}{v^2}$$

Comment: Can you please post a reference to the equation you want to either solve or derive?

Comment: Is this integral not possible?

Comment: its the (dx)2 thats bothering me

Comment: I kinda invented a problem and I also deduced some part of the solution which I think is erroneous but please tell me if this integral is possible or not . http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/283833/which-would-require-less-energy-to-rub-the-black-board

Comment: Muscle does no mechanical work on the **horizontal** motion of the object (unless accelerating). Work done $$W=\int_{C} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$$
The contraction of muscle converts chemical energy into internal energy (heat).  That's why you hold a dumbbell for a minutes, your muscle felt heat.

Comment: The integral, as written, makes no sense at all. The mistake the person who made it did was to just take the formula $s = \frac{1}{2}gt^2$ and replace $t$ by $dt = dx/v$ and $s$ by $dy$ and then 'integrate'. One cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the link posted in the last comment, the formula is obtained by assuming a horizontal movement with constant velocity $v$, and taking into account that - due to gravity $g $ - the arm falls by a distance $y$ as it moves horizontally by a distance  $x$. In particular, the time taken to fall by a distance $y$ is correctly estimated as $t=x/v$, so that the magnitude of $y $ is $1/2 \, g t^2=1/2 \, g \,(x^2/v^2) $.

Therefore, the work $W=mgy $, where $m $ indicates the mass, is

$$W(x)= mg \cdot 1/2 \, g \, (x^2/v^2)$$

$$ = 1/2 \,\frac {mg^2}{v^2} x^2$$

Note that, since the horizontal velocity as well as the vertical effect of gravity are both constant during the movement, the work $W $ can be directly calculated without integration as

$$W = 1/2 \frac {mg^2}{v^2} S^2$$

Also note that, if we decide to follow the integration procedure, this simply reduces to differentiating the $W (x) $ formula as

$$dW = 1/2 \frac {mg^2}{v^2} 2x dx$$

and then integrating it between $0$ and $S $. Because $\int  x dx = 1/2 \, x^2$, we get again the same formula above. Lastly, note that the quantity expressed as $(dx)^2$ used in your calculations corresponds to the $2x dx $ term.

Comment: But you see that when we move $\frac{S}{n}$ when n tends to infinity that is instantaneous. We are to imagine the movement of muscles, which is instantaneous but here I can't see the instantaneous calculation when S is very small y also has to be very small which is not the case here

Comment: Yes, the infinitesimal calculations are those showed above after differentiation. In particular, for an infinitesimal horizontal movement $dx $, that is to say $S/n $ with $N \rightarrow \infty $, the resulting infinitesimal work is $dW = 1/2 \frac {mg^2}{v^2} 2x dx$.